# docusign recipient authentication using saml using Admin Console/api

Tags: docusignapi

On docusign admin console, I was able to setup docusign recipient authentication using access-code, SMS and phone.
While trying for SAML, I received error message:
"Your envelope is incomplete. Recipient XXXX does not have SAML authentication setup adequately (missing assertion attribute values)".
Please share any information pertaining to how we may overcome this error message.

Comment: Does your account have SAML configuration setup? Page 5 of this documentation includes details on that: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/single-sign-on-functionality.pdf

Comment: Yes,Luis.The account from which I am sending email to recipients has SAML configuration setup. Given that my account has SAML configuration setup, what would be the step in admin console to send email to recipients mandating SAML authentication.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a supported feature for DocuSign. If wanting to use SAML, you must purchase SSO. Here is the latest implementation guide: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/single-sign-on-implementation-guide